# user that are active and have posts or articles

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get all active user that created or updated posts or/and articles

```
user(id,...)
post(id, created_by_id, updated_by_id, ...)
article(id, created_by_id, updated_by_id, ...)
```

I think I found a SQL request that is working:

```
select u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname
from user u, article a, post p
where u.is_active = true and (u.id = a.created_by_id or u.id = p.created_by_id or u.id = a.updated_by_id or u.id = p.updated_by_id)
group by u.id
```

Is it possible to add a virtual field that says if the user is just active or if he created or updated content (article or post)? Like that:

```
id - firstname - lastname - status

1  - John      - Doe      - active
2  - Bob       - One      - has content
3  - Alice     - Twotwo   - has content
4  - Luke      - Sky      - active
```

and what would be the request for that?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Add sample data and logic, how you would determine `status`.

Comment: If you want a virtual field you can create a `VIEW` where the status field is set with your request https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html

Comment: @Cyril F the answer you accepted will give you `has content` for users who did not create anything but have updated something. This is not what you asked for.

Comment: @forpas check my question, I asked for a query that gives me users that created OR updated content

Comment: *or if he created content (article or post)* do I miss anything?

Comment: my bad I said updated at the top of the question and then only created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with case statement.

```
 SELECT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname,
    CASE WHEN a.created_by_id is null &&  a.updated_by_id is null &&  p.created_by_id is null &&  p.updated_by_id is null THEN 'active'
    ELSE 'has content' 
    END as 'status'
    FROM User u
    LEFT JOIN post p ON u.id = p.created_by_id OR  u.id = p.updated_by_id
    LEFT JOIN article a ON u.id = a.created_by_id OR  u.id = a.updated_by_id
    WHERE u.is_active = 1
    ORDER BY u.id
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use  join explicitly not coma separated join and use union

```
 select u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname
 from user u  join
 article a on u.id=a.created_by_id or u.id=a.updated_by_id
 where u.is_active = true 
 union
  select u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname
 from user u  
 join post p on u.id=p.created_by_id or u.id=p.updated_by_id
 where u.is_active = true
```

Comment: That's not working as expected since it pulls all the users even if they have no content.

Comment: that way, that pulls only users with articles or with articles and posts, but not the users with posts and no article.

Answer (score 1):

You must join the tables and use CASE to create the new column:

```
select u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname,
case 
  when (a.created_by_id is not null) or (p.created_by_id is not null) then 'has content'
  else 'active'
end status
from user u left join article a 
on u.id=a.created_by_id or u.id=a.updated_by_id
left join post p on u.id=p.created_by_id or u.id=p.updated_by_id
where u.is_active = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `case when` expression and also it's best to use explicit join rather than comma separated join

```
select u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname,
case when u.is_active = true then 'active' else 'has content' end as 'status'
from user u inner join article a on u.id = a.created_by_id or u.id = a.updated_by_id
inner join post p on u.id = p.created_by_id or u.id = p.updated_by_id
where u.is_active = true
```